# xargs with multiple arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line-arguments, xargs

I have a source input, **input.txt**

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

I want to feed these input into a program as the following:

```
my-program --file=a.txt --file=b.txt --file=c.txt
```

So I try to use **xargs**, but with no luck.

```
cat input.txt | xargs -i echo "my-program --file"{}
```

It gives

```
my-program --file=a.txt
my-program --file=b.txt
my-program --file=c.txt
```

But I want

```
my-program --file=a.txt --file=b.txt --file=c.txt
```

Any idea?

Comment: `seq 1996 2022 |  xargs` calls for this when I'm trying to stripe my files by year on my file system.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

None of the solutions given so far deals correctly with file names containing space. Some even fail if the file names contain ' or ". If your input files are generated by users, you should be prepared for surprising file names.

[GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) deals nicely with these file names and gives you (at least) 3 different solutions. If your program takes 3 and only 3 arguments then this will work:

```
(echo a1.txt; echo b1.txt; echo c1.txt;
 echo a2.txt; echo b2.txt; echo c2.txt;) |
parallel -N 3 my-program --file={1} --file={2} --file={3}
```

Or:

```
(echo a1.txt; echo b1.txt; echo c1.txt;
 echo a2.txt; echo b2.txt; echo c2.txt;) |
parallel -X -N 3 my-program --file={}
```

If, however, your program takes as many arguments as will fit on the command line:

```
(echo a1.txt; echo b1.txt; echo c1.txt;
 echo d1.txt; echo e1.txt; echo f1.txt;) |
parallel -X my-program --file={}
```

Watch the intro video to learn more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Comment: Interesting - didn't know about GNU Parallel.  Bash is a sane shell; you don't need to put a backslash after a pipe to tell it that the rest of the command is on the next line.

Comment: GNU parallel is great.  One word of warning: On some systems you need to give parallel the "--gnu" option to make it work sensibly.
I never use xargs anymore. If you really don't want to parallelize you can always give it the "-j 1" option (1 job).

Comment: Utilite `parallel` is not always available, especially in plain unix and need to be installed if possible. There interesting solution [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25623391/2969544) available with standart unix tools.

Comment: [Another, more flexible solution with standard tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48184192/922340)

Answer (score 182):

Don't listen to all of them. :) Just look at this example:

```
echo argument1 argument2 argument3 | xargs -l bash -c 'echo this is first:$0 second:$1 third:$2'
```

Output will be:

```
this is first:argument1 second:argument2 third:argument3
```

Comment: If you're trying to do this on OSX, use -L1 e.g. `echo argument1 argument2 argument3 | xargs -L1 bash -c 'echo this is first:$0 second:$1 third:$2' | xargs`

Comment: But I think this answer is incorrect. The file has 3 lines but in this answer there are 3 argument in 1 line!

Comment: why is the pipe to xargs for the second time needed in the end?

Comment: You have to use double $ signs in a makefile. Example: `echo zero one | xargs -L1 -n 4 sh -c 'echo $$0'`

Comment: What does `-l bash` do?

Comment: It is worth noting that interactive applications might require adding the `-o` flag to `xargs`.

Comment: @LondonRob `-l` means "use at most MAX-LINES non-blank input lines per command line". default to 1 if not specified. `bash` has nothing to do with `-l`. We need bash for separating the one line string `argument1 argument2 argument3` to 3 different arguments by space. xargs doesn't do it automatically.

Comment: @TeaDrinker this sounds like it would be a useful addition to the answer. Want to propose an edit to the answer?

Comment: @LondonRob hmm... there's a highly chance that I don't have enough reputation again lol, I think the answer is ok now

Comment: Unlike the other solutions, this will work for my case when the args are not consecutive in the output.

Answer (score 23):

How about:

```
echo $'a.txt\nb.txt\nc.txt' | xargs -n 3 sh -c '
   echo my-program --file="$1" --file="$2" --file="$3"
' argv0
```

Answer (score 13):

It's simpler if you use two xargs invocations: 1st to transform each line into `--file=...`, 2nd to actually do the xargs thing ->

```
$ cat input.txt | xargs -I@ echo --file=@ | xargs echo my-program
my-program --file=a.txt --file=b.txt --file=c.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `sed` to prefix `--file=` to each line and then call `xargs`:

```
sed -e 's/^/--file=/' input.txt | xargs my-program
```

Comment: After Google'ing this (four years later), I came up with my own (similar) solution... specifically, for this question, it would be more like:  

`echo a.txt b.txt c.txt | xargs | sed 's/ / --file=/g' | xargs echo my-program --file`  

My complicated solution was more to pipe filenames (such as Apache logs) in to a long command line. For example:  

`ls /var/log/apache2/*access.log | xargs | sed 's/ / -f /g' | xargs echo myprogram -f`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution using sed for three arguments, but is limited in that it applies the same transform to each argument:

```
cat input.txt | sed 's/^/--file=/g' | xargs -n3 my-program
```

Here's a method that will work for two args, but allows more flexibility:

```
cat input.txt | xargs -n 2 | xargs -I{} sh -c 'V="{}"; my-program -file=${V% *} -file=${V#* }'
```

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled on a similar problem and found a solution which I think is nicer and cleaner than those presented so far.

The syntax for `xargs` that I have ended with would be (for your example):

```
xargs -I X echo --file=X
```

with a full command line being:

```
my-program $(cat input.txt | xargs -I X echo --file=X)
```

which will work as if

```
my-program --file=a.txt --file=b.txt --file=c.txt
```

was done (providing `input.txt` contains data from your example).

---

Actually, in my case I needed to first find the files and also needed them sorted so my command line looks like this:

```
my-program $(find base/path -name "some*pattern" -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 -I X echo --files=X)
```

Few details that might not be clear (they were not for me):

- `some*pattern` must be quoted since otherwise shell would expand it before passing to `find`.
- `-print0`, then `-z` and finally `-0` use null-separation to ensure proper handling of files with spaces or other wired names.

Note however that I didn't test it deeply yet. Though it seems to be working.

Comment: Thanks ! Using the `$(...)` to execute the command inline is much cleaner !

Comment: @DidiBear never use `some_command $(...)`, it's subject to glob expansion and word splitting; check this: `printf '%s\n' $(echo 'filename with * .txt')`, does it output `filename with * .txt`?

Answer (score 2):

xargs doesn't work that way.  Try:

```
  myprogram $(sed -e 's/^/--file=/' input.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `echo` prints a newline. Try something like

```
echo my-program `xargs --arg-file input.txt -i echo -n " --file "{}`
```

Comment: What happens when the input gets to 30,000 file names?

Comment: Use subshell expansion, like `echo my-program $(xargs --arg-file input.txt -i echo -n " --file "{})`

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution for this exact problem and came to the conclution of coding a **script in the midle**.

to transform the standard output for the next example use the -n '\n' delimeter

example:

```
 user@mybox:~$ echo "file1.txt file2.txt" | xargs -n1 ScriptInTheMiddle.sh

 inside the ScriptInTheMidle.sh:
 !#/bin/bash
 var1=`echo $1 | cut -d ' ' -f1 `
 var2=`echo $1 | cut -d ' ' -f2 `
 myprogram  "--file1="$var1 "--file2="$var2
```

For this solution to work you need to have a space between those arguments file1.txt and file2.txt, or whatever delimeter you choose, one more thing, inside the script make sure you check -f1 and -f2 as they mean "take the first word and take the second word" depending on the  first delimeter's position found (delimeters could be ' ' ';' '.' whatever you wish between single quotes . 
Add as many parameters as you wish.

Problem solved using xargs, cut , and some bash scripting.

Cheers!

if you wanna pass by I have some useful tips http://hongouru.blogspot.com

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's relatively easy:

`... | sed 's/^/--prefix=/g' | xargs echo | xargs -I PARAMS your_cmd PARAMS`

The `sed 's/^/--prefix=/g'` is optional, in case you need to prefix each param with some --prefix=.

The `xargs echo` turns the list of param lines (one param in each line) into a list of params in a single line and the `xargs -I PARAMS your_cmd PARAMS` allows you to run a command, placing the params where ever you want.

So `cat input.txt | sed 's/^/--file=/g' | xargs echo | xargs -I PARAMS my-program PARAMS` does what you need (assuming all lines within input.txt are simple and qualify as a single param value each).

Answer (score 1):

There is another nice way of doing this, if you do not know the number of files upront:

```sh
my-program $(find . -name '*.txt' -printf "--file=%p ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Nobody has mentioned echoing out from a loop yet, so I'll put that in for completeness sake (it would be my second approach, the sed one being the first):

```
for line in $(< input.txt) ; do echo --file=$line ; done | xargs echo my-program
```

Answer (score 0):

Old but this is a better answer:

```
cat input.txt | gsed "s/\(.*\)/\-\-file=\1/g" | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs my_program
```

# i like clean one liners
gsed is just gnu sed to ensure syntax matches version `brew install gsed` or just sed if your on gnu linux already...

test it:

```
cat input.txt | gsed "s/\(.*\)/\-\-file=\1/g" | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs echo my_program
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a more straightforward way. You can even customize the order of positional parameters to your liking, like in the demonstration below.

```bash
set $(cat input.txt)
my-program --file=$1 --file=$3 --file=$2
```

This works well in scenarios where you know the order and magnitude of arguments that are in the input.

Comment: `$(cat input.txt)` is subject to glob expansion and word-splitting. Don't use unquoted `$(...)` in a script!

Answer (score 0):

check this out too :

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
  my-program --file="$file"
done < input.txt
```

the while loop reads each line from the `input.txt` file and passes it as an argument to the `my-program` command with the `--file` flag!

Answer (score 0):

**Most answers don't take into account that some characters in the input lines can break `xargs` and unquoted `$(...)`.
Here are a few solutions that do the job correctly (i.e. robustly).**

---

**1. PURE BASH**

You can load the input lines into a `bash` array and prepend `--file=` to each element with a parameter expansion.
**WARNING!** You can't use this method for generating more than one argument per array element (for e.g. `‑f` `xxx.txt`).

```bash
readarray -t files < input.txt

my-program "${files[@]/#/--file=}"
```

**note:** if your `bash` doesn't have `readarray`/`mapfile` then you can use `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a files < input.txt` instead.

---

**2. AWK | XARGS -0**

You can use `awk` for prepending `--file=` to each line and generate a `NUL`-delimited stream that'll be safely processed by `xargs -0`:

```bash
awk '{printf("--file=%s%c",$0,0)}' input.txt |
xargs -0 my-program
```

---

**3. SED | XARGS**

If you ever need to be **POSIX** compliant:

```bash
sed -e 's/"/"\\""/g' -e 's/.*/--file="&"/' input.txt |
xargs my-program
```