# Recombine bash arguments when using pipeline

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

What approach can be used in case of recombine bash arguments,
for example:

```
echo "arg3 arg1 arg2" | ...
```

so as recombine arguments in random sort can be applicable:

```
... | some_command -arg1=$3 -arg2=$1 -arg3=$2 --interpretator-arg=$0 --anoter-arg=$1$2$3
```

Comment: Are you definitely looking to use `xargs` here? Could you show us a more concrete use case?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3770432/2088135

Comment: remove 'xargs' from original question. Command is not nessessarry.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use `read`:

```
echo "arg3 arg1 arg2" | { read -r a b c; some_command ...; }
```

Now you can use arguments `"$a"`, `"$b"` and `"$c"` as you wish.

I guess your example is a bit artificial but you can avoid a pipeline in this case:

```
{ read -r a b c; some_command ...; } <<< "arg3 arg1 arg2"
```

If the arguments really come from a command, then you can use a command substitution:

```
{ read -r a b c; some_command ...; } < <(command_producing_arguments)
```

Note that the semicolon at the end is important, if the command group `{ }` is written all on one line.