# Read a file line by line and run a java program

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

I need to run a java program that merge multiple files with a `*bam` extension. the structure of the program is:

```
java -jar mergefiles.jar \
I=file1.bam \
I=file2.bam \
I=file3.bam \
O=output.bam
```

So, I am trying the run this program for all *bam files in a directory. Initially, I try to create a list with the names of the *bam files (filenames.txt)

```
file1.bam
file2.bam
file3.bam
```

and using the 'while' command, like:

```
while read -r line; do
java -jar MergeFiles.jar \
I=$line \
O=output.bam
done < filenames.txt
```

However, the program executed for each `*bam` file in the text file but not all together (merge only one file per time, and overwrite the output). So, how I can run the program to merge all `*bam` files recursively?

Also, there are other option in the bash (e.g. using a loop for) to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use `xargs` or `parallel`. Take a look at [this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770432/xargs-with-multiple-arguments), it should do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you specify that you would like to use all `.bam` files in a dir, so instead of creating a file with the filenames, you should probably use [globbing](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) instead. Here's an example:

```
#! /bin/bash
# set nullglob to be safe
shopt -s nullglob
# read the filenames into an array
files=( *.bam )
# check that files actually exist
if (( ${#files[@]} == 0 )); then echo "no files" && exit 1; fi
# expand the array with a replacement
java -jar MergeFiles.jar \
"${files[@]/#/I=}" \
O=output.bam
```

The problem with your current solution is that the `while` loop will only read one line at a time, calling the command on each line separately.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @olli-k ! Work perfect!