# $ENV{$variable} in perl

Tags: perl, environment-variables

Is that anyway in Perl to expand the variable by in $ENV{$variable}?

I exported "a=T" and "T=b" in shell, and I run the Perl script in which print "$ENV{$a}\n", but nothing printed. I want to "b" can be printed, then how should I do in Perl?

Comment: you mean `$ENV{ $ENV{a} }` ...?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those environment variables should be chained you say, so

```
$ENV{ $ENV{a} };
```

Note: not `$a` but `a`, like `$ENV{USER}` etc. This uses the hash `%ENV` (see [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)), which has the current environment, so with keys being names of environment variables.

---

It is apparently of interest to use a Perl variable (for the shell variable's name<sup>†</sup>) in `%ENV`, and not a string literal as above. In that case we need to pass that shell variable, its name or the value, to the Perl program somehow so to have it stored in a variable; can't just use it directly.

Incidentally, one of the ways to pass a variable from shell to Perl is precisely by exporting it, what then makes it available via `%ENV`.  However, it can also be passed as usual, via command line. Assuming the use of a Perl one-liner (common in shell scripts), we have two options for how to pass

- As an argument, `perl -we'...'  "$var"`, in which case it is available in `@ARGV`
- Via the [`-s` command switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches), `perl -s -we'...' -- -shv="$var"`, what sets up `$shv` variable in the one-liner, with the value `$var`.  The `--` mark the start of arguments.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51713578/4653379) for details, and perhaps [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54059744/4653379) for another, more involved, example.

---

<sup>†</sup>  A comment asks how to pass variable's *name* (string `a`), not its value (`$a`). This doesn't seem as the best design to me; if the name of a variable for some reason need be passed around then it makes sense to store *that* in a variable (`var="a"`) and pass that variable, as above.

But if the idea is indeed to pass the name itself around, then do that instead, so either of

```
perl -we'...' "a"
perl -we'...' -s -- -shv="a"
```

The rest is the same and `%ENV` uses the variable that got assigned the input.

If a full Perl script is used (not a one-liner) then use [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) to nicely handle arugments.

Comment: thank you. Another question is if "a=T" is exported on the current shell, and in my Perl script : $test=a; print "$ENV{$ENV{test}}"; and then i run this script but it prints nothing. Can you help it again?

Comment: @michael_J Ah ... no, can't do that -- that shell's _environment_ variable `a` is provided in the `%ENV` hash, as a key.  But to use it as a "normal" variable in the Perl script you have to somehow pass it to the script; can't use either `a` or `$a`. One way to pass variables from the shell to a Perl script is in fact precisely by using the environment (you export the variable in the shell and then Perl script can use it via `%ENV`).  Or, you can pass it as an argument for the script (in two ways)

Comment: @michael_J  For how to pass Bash variables to a Perl one-liner, see for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51713578/4653379) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56200990/4653379) (perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54059744/4653379) can also be useful).  If you call a full Perl script (not one-liner) then I'd do away with all that and just nicely use command-line arguents via [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html)